# Compare map key (string) with letters in a vector

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on a project (AI in scrabble) and I'm trying to retrieve words from a map. I need to compare if there are enough letters in the "hand" to build the word. After comparing, I want to add that word (that is playable) into a vector.

```
void compareBotHand(std::vector<std::string> npcHand) //npcHand contains 7 random letters from the english alphabet
    {
        std::vector<std::string> botVec; //vector used to insert the playable words
        int matcher; //check if letters in "hand" and letters in word match
        std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = fR_existing_words.begin();
        while (it != fR_existing_words.end())
        {
            std::string fWord = it->first;
            matcher = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < fWord.length(); i++)
            {
                std::string s(1, fWord[i]); //convert char into string
                for (int j = 0; j < npcHand.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (npcHand[j] == fWord) //there are 1 letter words in the map
                    {
                        botVec.push_back(fWord);
                    }
                    else if (npcHand[j] == s)
                    {
                        matcher++;
                    }
                }
                if (matcher == fWord.length()) //if the number of letters in hand are the same has in word, they match
                {
                    botVec.push_back(fWord);
                }
            }
            it++;
        }
        std::cout << "Playable Words: " << std::endl;
        for (int c = 0; c < botVec.size(); c++)
        {
            std::cout << botVec[c] << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unsure about what you are asking. There doesn't seem to be a problem statement.

Comment: Well, I see one potential bug: `npcHand.erase(npcHand.begin() + j);` -- What happens if the next letter is one that needs to be erased, i.e. is equal to `s`?  You skip over it, due to your loop unconditionally incrementing `j` on every iteration.  The `erase` moves all the items in the vector "down" by 1 spot, so `j` should stay where it is.

Comment: Unrelated: 1. `botVec.clear();` is not necessary. A newly default constructed vector _is_ empty. 2. `npcHand = npcHandBack` implies that you made a backup - you didn't.

Comment: I suggest writing a dedicated function to check whether a word can be constructed with the letters available in a hand.  Something like:  `bool can_place(const std::string& word, const std::multiset<char>& hand)`.  It would make your code and asking your question a bit simpler.

Comment: @user4581301 I've updated my code and added a sc of the output, as you can see. As you can see, the third playable word shouldn't be there since I only have one "a" and it requires two.

Comment: One question is why you need to `erase` from the string to figure out if all of the letters of the hand is in the map.  Your method is slow compared to thinking of a way to do this linearly.   Also *do not post images*.  If someone wants to test a solution, they have to use an OCR to get your data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've edited my code, the problem that I have is that even words with letters that aren't on the go to the final vector. I'm still a beginner as far as i can tell and i know that having nested for loops and while loops inside each other is REALLY slow, but i can't seem to find a different/more efficient way of comparing two blocks of data

Comment: @NicholasM I have no idea what a multiset is, also, I don't want to change a lot of things because the game is already done. I'm just trying to make it "better" by creating a simple AI

Comment: You should start by writing simple functions first that do the basic:  `bool is_good_word(const std::string& scrabble_word, const std::string& your_hand)`.  Then write that function that returns either `true` or `false` if the `your_hand` can be played given the `scrabble_word`.  Note that both arguments are `const`.  This is basically an "interview" question that some are asked when applying for a programming job.  Hint -- no erasing needs to be done.  Once you write that function, it's just a matter of calling it in a loop for each of the scrabble words.

Comment: Hint #2 -- Start out with an array of 26 `int`'s that hold the count of all of the letters in your hand.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for the tip :D I'll change it now and give you some feedback.